# Return only one result for each partition of data

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'd like to be able to do some calculations by partition in BigQuery and then only output 1 row for each partition (rather than a row for every partition).  E.g., if I had something like this table:

```
Category | Location | Count
A        | 'home'   | 20
A        | 'work'   | 10
A        | 'lab'    | 6
B        | 'home'   | 5
C        | 'lab'    | 15
C        | 'home'   | 25
```

And I'd like to end up with this result

```
Category  | TopLocation     | TopCount | SecondLocation | SecondCount
A         | 'home'          | 20       | 'work'         | 10
B         | 'home'          | 5        | NULL           | NULL
C         | 'home'          | 25       | 'lab'          | 15
```

I thought I could do this with partitions, but this ends up generating a row for every value, rather than the single row that I want, so I then group by category and use `FIRST`. Is there a better way to do this that avoids generating so many intermediary rows (and, hopefully, avoids the 'large results' issue with window functions).

```
SELECT
  category,
  FIRST(TopLocation) TopLocation,
  FIRST(TopCount) TopCount,
  FIRST(SecondLocation) SecondLocation,
  FIRST(SecondCount) SecondCount,
FROM
  (SELECT
      category,
      NTH_VALUE(Location, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY count) TopLocation,
      NTH_VALUE(Count, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY count) TopCount,
      NTH_VALUE(Location, 2) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY count) SecondLocation,
      NTH_VALUE(Count, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY count) SecondCount
   FROM
      mytable
   )    
GROUP BY
  category
ORDER BY
  category DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update: A better solution with #standardSQL**

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/45112050/132438

---

How about:

```
SELECT word, word_count, corpus, rank FROM (
  SELECT word, word_count, corpus,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY corpus ORDER BY word_count DESC) rank
  FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
  WHERE word_count > 6
)
WHERE rank<3
```

Comment: that still ends up with 3 rows per corpus though.

Comment: You are right - I'm trying to figure out an alternative, but your query looks pretty good for the intended purpose. Note the use of word_count>6 on my queyr to filter out the long tail (useful for the 'large results' issue).

Answer (score 0):

this should do the work:

```
select category, 
    first(if(rank = 1, location, null)) as location_1, first(if(rank = 1, count, null)) as count_1,
    first(if(rank = 2, location, null)) as location_2, first(if(rank = 2, count, null)) as count_2,
    first(if(rank = 3, location, null)) as location_3, first(if(rank = 3, count, null)) as count_3
from
    (select row_number() over (partition by category order by count desc) as rank, * 
from 
    (select 'A' as category, 'home' AS location, 20 as count),
    (select 'A' as category, 'work' AS location, 10 as count),
    (select 'A' as category, 'lab' AS location, 6 as count),
    (select 'B' as category, 'home' AS location, 5 as count),
    (select 'C' as category, 'lab' AS location, 15 as count),
    (select 'C' as category, 'home' AS location, 25 as count)
)
group by category order by category
```

result:

```
Row category    location_1  count_1 location_2  count_2 location_3  count_3  
1   A   home    20  work    10  lab 6    
3   B   home    5   null    null    null    null
2   C   home    25  lab 15  null    null
```

but probably won't solve the problem with 'large query result' on window function