# BigQuery - Time Series and most efficient way to select the 'latest' record

Tags: google-bigquery

In our BQ design we have a customer table (nested raw data) which is event sourced from our microservices layer (consuming of kinesis steams), where each event has the latest entity snapshot for the entity the event is for (post processing image after the change).  A sort of modern change data capture I guess.

This latest snapshot in each event is how we populate BigQuery - it is extracted and loaded into biqQuery (via apache spark structured steaming connector) in an APPEND ONLY mode. (This is different to say mutating and updating one row for a given ID)

So given this is append only, the size of this table can grow of course over time - an entry per change from an event.  However it quite nicely is a full, timeseries of customer state and changes (our requirement to have), and is immutable as such.  We can rebuild the full warehouse by replaying the events for example....enough on the context.

One consequence of this is the fact that loading into BigQuery may result in duplicates (e.g if spark error and retries a micro batch, BQ isnt an idempotent structured streaming sink when loading by jobs, or just due to distributed nature its generally possible).  SteamingInserts might be something to look into later as it helps with deduping.....

The result of this architecture is that I need a view ontop of the raw time series data (remember can occasionally have duplicates) that returns the LATEST record under these conditions.

Latest is determined by a metadata struct field on the customer record (metadata.lastUpdated) - and the row with the MAX(metadata.lastUpdated) is the latest.  This is guarneteed by our MS layer.

This is a true event time timestamp as well.  The table id DAY partitioned and has a _PARTITIONTIME column, but this is just an ingest time and I cant use this.  Be great when I can specify a column to be used as the partition time! (wishlist).

A duplicate will be two rows with the SAME customer 'id' AND 'metadata.lastUpdated' - so MAX(metadata.lastUpdated) could return 2 rows, so I need to use

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY .... so I can select the rowNum=1

In my view as well to only select 1 row where there is dups.

Ok so enough words/context (sorry), below is my view SQL to get the latest.  It works from my tests, but I am not sure it is the most efficient way to achieve my outcome when the size of the table / number of rows gets large, and was wondering if any BigQuery boffins out there might have a more efficient / clever SQL to do this?  Why SQL is OK, but by no means an expert in performance tuning for sure and in particular the best ways to do SQL for BQ perf tunning.

I was just hoping to be able to have all the data in one table and rely on the power of the dremel engine to just query it, rather then needing to have multiple tables or do anyting too complex.

SO my SQL is below.  Note - my timestamp is ingested as a string, so need to PARSE this in the view too.

```
WITH
  cus_latest_watermark AS (
  SELECT
    id,
    MAX(PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S%Ez", metadata.lastUpdated)) AS maxLastUpdatedTimestampUTC
  FROM
    `project.dataset.customer_refdata`
  GROUP BY
    id ),
  cust_latest_rec_dup AS (
  SELECT
    cus.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cus.id ORDER BY cus.id) AS rowNum
  FROM
    `project.dataset.customer_refdata` cus
  JOIN
    cus_latest_watermark
  ON
    cus.id = cus_latest_watermark.id
    AND PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S%Ez", cus.metadata.lastUpdated) = cus_latest_watermark.maxLastUpdatedTimestampUTC)
SELECT
  cust_latest_rec_dup.* EXCEPT(rowNum)
FROM
  cust_latest_rec_dup
WHERE
  rowNum = 1
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH cus_watermark AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S%Ez", metadata.lastUpdated) AS UpdatedTimestampUTC
  FROM `project.dataset.customer_refdata`
),
cust_latest_rec_dup AS (
  SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY UpdatedTimestampUTC DESC) AS rowNum
  FROM cus_watermark
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(rowNum)
FROM cust_latest_rec_dup
WHERE rowNum = 1
```

You can play/test this approach with below dummy data

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.customer_refdata` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '2017-07-14 16:47:27' AS lastUpdated UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2017-07-14 16:47:27' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2017-07-14 17:47:27' UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, '2017-07-14 18:47:27' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-07-14 16:57:27' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-07-14 17:57:27' UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '2017-07-14 18:57:27' 
),
cus_watermark AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%d %T", lastUpdated) AS UpdatedTimestampUTC
  FROM `project.dataset.customer_refdata`
),
cust_latest_rec_dup AS (
  SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY UpdatedTimestampUTC DESC) AS rowNum
  FROM cus_watermark
)
SELECT * EXCEPT(rowNum)
FROM cust_latest_rec_dup
WHERE rowNum = 1
```

Comment: Mikhail thanks heaps for replying (again) will try this tweek can see you are using the ORDER BY DESC in the partition - one thing, I still need to select all the columns from `project.dataset.customer_refdata` table itself as the final projection.  Appreciate your input!

Comment: yes - all columns, that is how it works. just replace `id` with `*` in cus_watermark sub-select

Comment: Also, if you want to preserve ONLY original columns  - you should add `UpdatedTimestampUTC` field into EXCEPT list

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant - proposing an ARRAY_AGG alternative at https://stackoverflow.com/a/45112050/132438

Comment: and now got the '*' part thanks to Elliot :) @MikhailBerlyant

Comment: just saw it - obviously nice. Looks like I was a little lazy today :o)

Answer (score 9):

I'm a big fan of Mikhail, and we've been doing queries like OVER(ORDER) for a long time - but let me propose an alternative made possible thanks to #standardSQL.

This query fails, because it has too many elements to ORDER BY in a single partition:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT repo.name, type, actor.id as actor, payload, created_at
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY actor.id ORDER BY created_at DESC) rn
  FROM `githubarchive.month.201706` 
)
WHERE rn=1
ORDER BY created_at
LIMIT 100


"Error: Resources exceeded during query execution."
```

Meanwhile this query runs in 15 seconds:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT actor, event
FROM (
  SELECT actor.id actor, 
    ARRAY_AGG(
      STRUCT(type, repo.name, payload, created_at) 
      ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1
    ) events
  FROM `githubarchive.month.201706` 
  GROUP BY 1
), UNNEST(events) event
ORDER BY event.created_at
LIMIT 100
```

This because the ORDER BY is allowed to drop everything - except the top record - on each GROUP BY.

And if you want all records, the equivalent to SELECT * (thanks Elliott):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT event.* FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(
    t ORDER BY t.created_at DESC LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)]  event
  FROM `githubarchive.month.201706` t 
  GROUP BY actor.id
)
ORDER BY created_at
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Thank you Felipe :o) Just as FYI: the reason I decided not to include this option in my answer is because users requirement: `I still need to select all the columns` which i thought will make this option a little more complex to adjust. but agree this is a good option in general and might have better chances to succeed on massive data!

Comment: True - we can't * this STRUCT() :)

Comment: If you want to include all fields in the struct with `ARRAY_AGG`, you can use `ARRAY_AGG((SELECT AS STRUCT t.*) ...` after giving an alias of `t` to the table.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard got it! It wasn't straightforward, but see query 3. Thanks!

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/a/43851309/5221944 to see what still needs to be fixed in your latest version :o)

Comment: oh, you had done it earlier! - but what's the missing fix?

Comment: your output produces record that includes all original fields - so original structure is broken. there might be better way to address this  - but i just did one more outer query - so final output is exactly same schema as original

Comment: Hi all wow great comments and chat guys!  @felipe-hoffa - legend (as is mikhail-berlyant and elliott-brossard) thanks guys for the updated example.  Ill need to play a bit today to get my head around this, vant wait.  Love learning these optimisation techniques for BQ.

Comment: @felipe-hoffa Am I correct in stating the table decoration for partitioning is not supported yet in Standard SQL?  Not sure even if partitioning is right for me (yet) - the problem I have with it is that its on ingest time not true event time that I can configure BQ to use instead (which Dan indicated is a feature on the roadmap on the drill to detail podcast?)  Now that will be a super cool feature!  The other feature would be streamingUpsert (or update).....our use case is append only, which is great, but with Spark for example could use upsert the sink operation for spark update mode..cool!

Comment: One thing on this - is there a reason for the limit 100 on the outer query?  I understand the limit 1 on the inner, grabbing the top row after ordering desc....I would still want the 'latest' for every unique id, not the latest 100....or is this another BQ trick :)

Comment: you can ignore limit 100 - it is just to limit output as it is just example.