# Maximum Values for Day, Category Aggregations?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**Goal**: Output only (category, sum of incidents) for each day of the week (unique) across 2018.

i.e. Show the *top* category and its total sum of incidents for each day of the week. There should therefore only be 7 rows with this dataset (but `LIMIT 7` doesn't really answer the core problem I'm trying to understand)

Using BigQuery Standard SQL:

```
SELECT
    dayofweek,
    category,
    SUM(incident_count) as incidents
FROM
    (SELECT dayofweek, category, count(*) as incident_count
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.san_francisco.sfpd_incidents`
    WHERE
        EXTRACT(year from timestamp) = 2018
    GROUP BY
        category, dayofweek
) incidents_2018
GROUP BY
    category,
    dayofweek
ORDER BY incidents DESC
```

---

I've tried writing a `HAVING` clause with a sub-query to filter the aggregated results - resembling `HAVING incidents > (SELECT count(*) FROM sfpd_incidents WHERE ...)` - but I'm stuck in understanding what that sub-query should look like.

```
|dayofweek|         category          |incidents|
|---------|---------------------------|--------:|
|Monday   |LARCENY/THEFT              |      228|
|Wednesday|LARCENY/THEFT              |      210|
|Tuesday  |LARCENY/THEFT              |      194|
|Thursday |LARCENY/THEFT              |      119|
|Friday   |LARCENY/THEFT              |      118|
|Saturday |LARCENY/THEFT              |      115|
|Sunday   |LARCENY/THEFT              |      108|
# this should be the cut-off point - only show the
# top category & its count for each dayofweek
# incident counts that aren't the "top" for each
# dayofweek should be excluded from the result set.
|Monday   |NON-CRIMINAL               |      105|
|Tuesday  |OTHER OFFENSES             |       91|
|Wednesday|OTHER OFFENSES             |       85|
|Tuesday  |NON-CRIMINAL               |       78|
|Monday   |OTHER OFFENSES             |       72|
|Monday   |ASSAULT                    |       68|
|Wednesday|NON-CRIMINAL               |       62|
|Tuesday  |ASSAULT                    |       62|
|Wednesday|ASSAULT                    |       51|
|Sunday   |ASSAULT                    |       50|
|Thursday |ASSAULT                    |       47|
```

Comment: is the cutoff value a constant?

Comment: i didn't get what is your problem. can you clarify? can  you provide simplified example of input and expected output?

Comment: No, it should be calculated dynamically - put another way, the cutoff value is whenever we have seen a distinct value for each `dayofweek` already. Otherwise `HAVING incidents > 105` would suffice.

Comment: what if the top category has data for less than 7 days? what should be in the output then?

Comment: In that case, we should show whichever category has the highest SUM for that day. It just happens that (for obvious reasons) larceny/theft is the top on every day for this dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT dayofweek, category, incident_count
FROM (SELECT dayofweek, category, count(*) as incident_count,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dayofweek ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM `bigquery-public-data.san_francisco.sfpd_incidents`
      WHERE EXTRACT(year from timestamp) = 2018
      GROUP BY category, dayofweek
     ) incidents_2018
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY incident_count DESC;
```

Comment: That shows the correct data. Would you mind explaining the thinking behind how ROW_NUMBER() and OVER come into play here (so I can tackle this in the future)? Thanks!

Comment: For better scalability, also try ARRAY_AGG(ORDER BY LIMIT 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/45112050/132438

Comment: @elithrar . . . `ROW_NUMBER()`  assigns a sequential number.  This is used to return the top value for each day of the week.

Comment: That makes sense. We get a partition ordered by row number, and we take only the top row of that partition (seqnum = 1)

Comment: @Felipe Hoffa - what makes `ARRAY_AGG` more scalable? Your comment in the linked thread says **This because the ORDER BY is allowed to drop everything - except the top record - on each GROUP BY.** - is this not an option with each partition?

Comment: @elithrar  . . . Most databases would do the sort *withing each partition* and then apply the limit.  It would appear that BigQuery is smarter than that.  It knows that it wants <n> records, so it allocates an array of that size and then fills it with the top values as they appear.  Anything that doesn't fit in that space gets discarded.  This is likely to be faster than `row_number()` because sorting a small fixed number of elements is faster than sorting a large list.  It is definitely less resource intensive.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for BigQuery Standard SQL (and looks closer to your original query so you might better understand it)

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  dayofweek, 
  ARRAY_AGG(
    STRUCT<category STRING, incidents INT64>(category, incident_count) 
    ORDER BY incident_count DESC 
    LIMIT 1
  )[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].*
FROM (
  SELECT dayofweek, category, COUNT(*) AS incident_count
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.san_francisco.sfpd_incidents`
  WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM TIMESTAMP) = 2018
  GROUP BY category, dayofweek
) incidents_2018
GROUP BY dayofweek
ORDER BY incidents DESC
```

Slightly shorter (less verbose version) is

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  ARRAY_AGG(incidents_2018 ORDER BY incident_count DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)].*
FROM (
  SELECT dayofweek, category, COUNT(*) AS incident_count
  FROM `bigquery-public-data.san_francisco.sfpd_incidents`
  WHERE EXTRACT(year FROM TIMESTAMP) = 2018
  GROUP BY category, dayofweek
) incidents_2018
GROUP BY incidents_2018.dayofweek
ORDER BY incident_count DESC
```

for both options  - output is

```
Row dayofweek   category        incident_count   
1   Monday      LARCENY/THEFT   228  
2   Wednesday   LARCENY/THEFT   210  
3   Tuesday     LARCENY/THEFT   194  
4   Thursday    LARCENY/THEFT   119  
5   Friday      LARCENY/THEFT   118  
6   Saturday    LARCENY/THEFT   115  
7   Sunday      LARCENY/THEFT   108
```

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. For further understanding: we’re capturing just the first element of each array with `OFFSET[0]` - where does `SAFE_` come into play here? What case would there exist no elements in that array / no elements to put into the array? The wildcard selector is otherwise selecting all of the first elements of each array (partition, really) for aggregation in our GROUP BY later.

Comment: `SAFE_OFFSET` is just part of best practice that I learned to use for myself  - in your case you can use just `OFFSET` . And correct about wildcard here - it says out put all elements of resulted `STRUCT`