# BQ - Event Timeseries Report for Latest State

Tags: google-bigquery

Ive been around the houses on below as a test for a timeseries report, requiring each day to have the single latest event, for a given EntityId, up to and including that day (can be gaps) but not considering future ones. i.e what did that entityState look like on historic day x

Ive created the shell code below Ive been using, with test data and comments embedded.

What is the most efficient way to do this?  Guessing some ARRAY_AGG is involved with some LEAD/LAG navigation?  Im stuck anyway any help greatly appreciated, comments inline with the code to explain the test scenario.

```
-- Goal 
--    : a contiguous date range from 2020-06-01 to 2020-06-12 with a single record for each unique entity state (1,2,3 - test data has 3 unique entities) for each date  i.e what was the historic state on a given date.
--    : for each date, each entity (if it existed on or before the date) always needs a single event record containing its 'latest' EntityFullState at the end of that given day (i.e most recent state event up to and including that date - filter out later dated events)
--    : there are gaps of days between some events, but we still need to have a single entry for every day for event entity
WITH 
  -- imagine these as 'update' events at a point in time
  -- unique events for a given EntityId, over 10 days.  
  -- Can have some for same entity on the same day - the 'latest' 
  test_events AS (
    SELECT "EVID_1" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-01 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "1" AS EntityId, "Entity 1 - 1st Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_2" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-01 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "2" AS EntityId, "Entity 2 - 1st Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_3" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-02 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "3" AS EntityId, "Entity 3 - 1st Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_4" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-03 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "1" AS EntityId, "Entity 1 - 2nd Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_5" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-04 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "1" AS EntityId, "Entity 1 - 3rd Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_6" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-04 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "2" AS EntityId, "Entity 2 - 2nd Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_7" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-04 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "3" AS EntityId, "Entity 3 - 2nd Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_8" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-06 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "1" AS EntityId, "Entity 1 - 4th Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_9" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-08 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "2" AS EntityId, "Entity 2 - 3rd Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL -- 2 events same day for '2'
    SELECT "EVID_10" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-08 02:00:00") AS EventTs, "2" AS EntityId, "Entity 2 - Last Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL -- 2 events same day for '2', this is 1 hour later so is 'latest'
    SELECT "EVID_11" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-09 23:59:59") AS EventTs, "3" AS EntityId, "Entity 3 - 3rd Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL -- 2 events split over midnight for boundry testing for '3'
    SELECT "EVID_11" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-10 00:00:00") AS EventTs, "3" AS EntityId, "Entity 3 - Last Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_12" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-11 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "1" AS EntityId, "Entity 1 - Last Event" AS EntityFullState
  ),
  
  all_dates AS ( -- want contiguous days no gaps, use this as a calendar template
  SELECT
    dt
  FROM (
    SELECT
      GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2020-06-01', '2020-06-12', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS arr
    ) da,
    UNNEST(da.arr) dt
  ),
  
  report AS (
  SELECT
    d.dt AS ReportDate,
    -- TODO rest of events join logic, single event, per entity, representing the newest event up to and including the report date.
  FROM
    all_dates d
  )
  
SELECT
  *
FROM
  report r
ORDER BY
  ReportDate
```

Comment: Hi! I would like to share another Stackoverflow [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45107775/bigquery-time-series-and-most-efficient-way-to-select-the-latest-record), which could be helpful for your needs. Let me know if it is sufficient for you.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - that picks the latest at current time, this needs to be the latest at every historic day in history from some starty point, which is different and seemingly much harder

Answer (score 0):

Think perhaps i tried to overcomplicate with arrays :). Below works I think

```
-- Goal 
--    : a contiguous date range from 2020-06-01 to 2020-06-12 with a single record for each unique entity state (1,2,3 - test data has 3 unique entities) for each date  i.e what was the historic state on a given date.
--    : for each date, each entity (if it existed on or before the date) always needs a single event record containing its 'latest' EntityFullState at the end of that given day (i.e most recent state event up to and including that date - filter out later dated events)
--    : there are gaps of days between some events, but we still need to have a single entry for every day for event entity
WITH 
  -- imagine these as 'update' events at a point in time
  -- unique events for a given EntityId, over 10 days.  
  -- Can have some for same entity on the same day - the 'latest' 
  test_events AS (
    SELECT "EVID_1" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-01 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "1" AS EntityId, "Entity 1 - 1st Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_2" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-01 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "2" AS EntityId, "Entity 2 - 1st Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_3" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-02 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "3" AS EntityId, "Entity 3 - 1st Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_4" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-03 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "1" AS EntityId, "Entity 1 - 2nd Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_5" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-04 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "1" AS EntityId, "Entity 1 - 3rd Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_6" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-04 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "2" AS EntityId, "Entity 2 - 2nd Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_7" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-04 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "3" AS EntityId, "Entity 3 - 2nd Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_8" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-06 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "1" AS EntityId, "Entity 1 - 4th Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_9" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-08 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "2" AS EntityId, "Entity 2 - 3rd Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL -- 2 events same day for '2'
    SELECT "EVID_10" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-08 02:00:00") AS EventTs, "2" AS EntityId, "Entity 2 - Last Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL -- 2 events same day for '2', this is 1 hour later so is 'latest'
    SELECT "EVID_11" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-09 23:59:59") AS EventTs, "3" AS EntityId, "Entity 3 - 3rd Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL -- 2 events split over midnight for boundry testing for '3'
    SELECT "EVID_11" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-10 00:00:00") AS EventTs, "3" AS EntityId, "Entity 3 - Last Event" AS EntityFullState UNION ALL
    SELECT "EVID_12" AS EventId, TIMESTAMP("2020-06-11 01:00:00") AS EventTs, "1" AS EntityId, "Entity 1 - Last Event" AS EntityFullState
  ),
  
  test_events_nav AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityId ORDER BY EventTs) AS EntityEventSeq,
    LEAD(EventTs) OVER (PARTITION BY EntityId ORDER BY EventTs) AS NextEventTs,
    LAG(EventTs) OVER (PARTITION BY EntityId ORDER BY EventTs) AS PreviousEventTs,
  FROM
    test_events
  ),
  
  all_dates AS ( -- want contiguous days no gaps, use this as a calendar template
  SELECT
    dt
  FROM (
    SELECT
      GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY('2020-06-01 23:59:59', '2020-06-12 23:59:59', INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS arr
    ) da,
    UNNEST(da.arr) dt
  ),
  
  report AS (
  SELECT
    d.dt AS ReportDate,
    e.*
  FROM
    test_events_nav e,
    all_dates d
  WHERE
    d.dt BETWEEN e.EventTs AND NextEventTs 
    OR (d.dt < e.EventTs AND PreviousEventTs IS NULL)    
    OR (d.dt > e.EventTs AND NextEventTs IS NULL)
  )
  
SELECT
  *
FROM
  report r
ORDER BY
  ReportDate
```

Comment: if theres is a more efficient cleaver way please do let me know

Comment: i actually had to change the generated array to timestamp to cater of multiple events in the same day