# Sampling time series data in SQL

Tags: sql

I am pretty new to SQL and have a question about sampling time-series data from SQL. I have an example dataset below, which contains measurements from 2 devices sampled in different intervals.

| timestamp | devicename | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:05 | device1 | 8.22 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:07 | device2 | 10.53 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:08 | device1 | 11.44 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:11 | device1 | 8.08 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:12 | device2 | 8.85 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:14 | device1 | 9.49 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:17 | device1 | 9.98 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:17 | device2 | 8.62 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:20 | device1 | 11.62 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:22 | device2 | 11.2 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:23 | device1 | 9.03 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:26 | device1 | 8.33 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:27 | device2 | 10.58 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:29 | device1 | 8.26 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:32 | device2 | 9.1 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:32 | device1 | 11.77 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:35 | device1 | 10.12 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:37 | device2 | 11.49 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:38 | device1 | 11.39 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:41 | device1 | 8.22 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:42 | device2 | 9.47 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:44 | device1 | 8.77 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:47 | device2 | 9.41 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:47 | device1 | 11.2 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:50 | device1 | 11.98 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:52 | device2 | 8.62 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:53 | device1 | 11.66 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:56 | device1 | 11.14 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:57 | device2 | 11.99 |
| 01/04/2010 08:03:59 | device1 | 10.08 |
| 01/04/2010 08:04:02 | device2 | 9.36 |
| 01/04/2010 08:04:02 | device1 | 9.8 |
| 01/04/2010 08:04:05 | device1 | 10.69 |
| 01/04/2010 08:04:07 | device2 | 11.82 |
| 01/04/2010 08:04:12 | device2 | 8.33 |
| 01/04/2010 08:04:17 | device2 | 11.13 |
| 01/04/2010 08:04:22 | device2 | 8.82 |
| 01/04/2010 08:04:27 | device2 | 10.72 |
| 01/04/2010 08:04:32 | device2 | 9.82 |
| 01/04/2010 08:04:37 | device2 | 8.39 |
| 01/04/2010 08:04:42 | device2 | 11.46 |
| 01/04/2010 08:04:47 | device2 | 10.23 |

The thing that I am trying to do is to sample data in a specified interval (say 8 seconds) so that I will get a table like this:

[image: Sampled data]

Of course, it requires interpolation for the intervals where no measurement is taken but is it possible to do this with SQL or does it require post-processing with something else (Python etc.)?

Comment:  Please consider not posting [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, an image can't be used or searched on etc.

Comment: What's expected to happen if an interval has no samples at all?

Comment: @Stu Thanks for the comment. I can also post an editable version.

Comment: @jarlh It will do a linear interpolation. The aim is to get a common sampling interval for all measurements.

Comment: I have a technical answer that I'm trying to summarise, but can I ask why? Normalisation like this reduces the accuracy of time-series data, even if you make the interval smaller than the average interval between events. There are usually better ways to answer the question of _why?_ What sort of analysis will you perform over the transformed data that you think this will help with?

Comment: Please include a larger dataset, 4 and 3 points is not really enough to demonstrate the common pitfals that you might encounter with this.

Comment: Also what RDBMS are you using? Date and Time functions are not standard across the vendors.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller RDBMS is BigQuery. The answer for your "why" question is that I have several devices measuring temperatures of different rooms in a building. I would like to do multivariate analysis and then I will run an optimization model to predict the optimal HVAC settings. The sampling interval in question will be used to test how frequently I need to run this optimization. I am not deeply concerned about the accuracy of the data after interpolation and aware of the loss of some accuracy of the data. I hope this clears the question a bit.

Comment: Have a read here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45107775/1690217 or off site: [Medium: Time Series Analytics with BigQuery](https://medium.com/google-cloud/time-series-analytics-with-bigquery-f65867c1ce74)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is possible, but it is hard to be efficient, often with *time-series* data the performance is a more significant factor in assessing the feasibility of the solution than the architecture you think you want to use.
>
> - There are other types of databases that have better in built support for time-series storage and analysis.
>
> > Traditionally we would try to avoid *normalising* the data intervals in the database. Once you *interpolate* the events and values into regular timeframes you will lose accuracy of the information. This can have significant effects on some types of calculations and visualisations, especially when *down-sampling* occurs, when multiple values need to be represented by a single event.

The first question is this: **Are you going to *down-sample* events** or do you only need to inject missing values over a maximum interval. If you are down-sampling, will you simply take the numerical average between the X values that occur in that window or will you use a linear average or triangulation to find the average mid point between the values or is it important to find the value that would visually represent the most similar output on a chart if you overlayed the *normalised* data with the *raw* data. In fact is average appropriate at all, do you need the minimum, maximim or both?

- The effect can be significant, especially if the frequency of the data reads is high or varies a lot.

Fundamentally in SQL we cannot *inject* rows, we can only filter out existing rows or produce aggregates. This means that if your interval is always greater than the number of points available in the interval then simple aggregates can work, but it is a volatile solution that depends on the frequency of the data.

If you only need a *numerical average* between the points, (effectively ignoring time) we can use simple `GROUP BY`. For this to produce a *regular* interval though, we need to key the interval to data outside of the recordset, if the interval is 8 seconds we can truncate the `timestamp` to the nearest 8 seconds and use that as the `GROUP BY` key.

- The following syntax is SQL Server, not all versions support `DATE_TRUNC` yet so we'll use a first principals approach

```
   -- Key to a specific date (so that seconds doesn't overflow INT)
   DECLARE @ZeroDate DATETIME = '2010-04-01 08:03:00';
   SELECT DATEADD(ss, DATEDIFF(ss, @ZeroDate, timestamp) - DATEDIFF(ss, @ZeroDate, timestamp) % 8, @ZeroDate) as timestamp
         , devicename
         , AVG(value) as Average
         , MIN(value) as Minimum
         , MAX(value) as Maximum
   FROM #Events 
   GROUP BY DATEADD(ss, DATEDIFF(ss, @ZeroDate2, timestamp) - DATEDIFF(ss, @ZeroDate2, timestamp) % 8, @ZeroDate2), devicename
   ORDER BY devicename, timestamp
```

This gives us 2 values from the original series, which is enough to prove the issues.

#### raw data

| timestamp | devicename | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/04/2010 8:03:05 | device1 | 10.1 |
| 1/04/2010 8:03:08 | device1 | 8.6 |
| 1/04/2010 8:03:11 | device1 | 9.9 |
| 1/04/2010 8:03:14 | device1 | 11.4 |

[image: Loss of accuracy]

#### averaged data

| timestamp | devicename | Average | Minimum | Maximum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2010-04-01 08:03:00.000 | device1 | 10.1000003814697 | 10.1 | 10.1 |
| 2010-04-01 08:03:08.000 | device1 | 9.96666653951009 | 8.6 | 11.4 |

The trend of the raw data is clearly to be increasing, where as the observable trend in the average data is actually *decreasing*. If you were to round the values you could even observe no significant change across this set at all.

This is of course a contrived example, but the results extrapolate to any real-world set. The other issue is what to do if there are 2 points very close together with a significant variation, this might produce a desirable or undesirable result depending on your needs. The peaks or troughs might be significant to your needs.

As we said that SQL cannot *inject* missing rows, if you need to inject frames into the *gaps* in the data then you need an alternate datasource that can key the interval frames for you. Keeping in mind then that for the missing frame, the average of the values is zero, so you might want to calculate the average in this case from the value of the previous frame and the value in the next frame either side of the *gap*. If the gaps are in-frequent and *always* onyl 1 interval, then a cheap hack is to find the average points from one key frame, then shift the frame half of the interval, union with the original set and then find the average again.

There are all sorts of techniques, including using numbers tables or recursion to inject the missing data, and then you can use window functions like LEAD and LAG to get the values either side of a gap.

- *Calculating the values is not generally the problem, there are common techniques with standard implementations translated into many different database environments.*

A general usage pattern that emerges in time-series data like storing real world telemetry is that the data is usually only *written* to once, or very infrequently updated and is *read* many, many more times. When we have a data interactions like this in SQL we are encouraged to store the data using a structure that is optimised for reading but may have a much more expensive *write* process (in terms of time and effort).

With this in mind, the *optimimal* solution is one where the interpolation of intervals, and as many other calculations and analysis you can perform, like trends and differentials are calculated *before* the data is written. It may be practical to do this in the application layer, or via a caching framework or streaming infrastructure or you could use another table in the database.

You might stage this in hourly or daily lots, log the raw data into one table, then at a slower regular interval process the next batch of results into another table that you will use for your reporting or analytics.

- So while you *can* do this in SQL, often it is better *not* too depending on the complexity of your algorithm. If we are processing in batches then it might be appropriate to select the data for that batch out of the database for processing in your service/lambda/logic or application layer and then insert the results back.